# iPad 2018 locks although auto lock never

Tags: ipad

My new iPad 2018 11.3.1 has auto lock "never", 90% battery, watching Safari streaming, after 30 minuted it auto locks and requires my pin. Why? I doubled checked the settings above, happened again! Why?

Heres a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Can you please post a screenshot where your auto-lock setting is set to Never?  Also, see [ask] for good tips on how to ask questions.  - From Review